# Why can not we use lowercase letters as class member variable in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, variables

```
class A
  AB = 123
  def print_var
    print AB
  end
end
A.new.print_var
```

The above code prints 123.

```
class B
  ab = 245
  def print_var
    print ab
  end
end
```

This codes throws an error, saying undefined local variable or method `ab'. Why is it so? Is there a naming convention while declaring ruby class member variables?

Comment: as stated below `@@` defines a class variable. You can see the class variables by calling `A.class_variables` and it will output all defined class variables.

Answer (score 8):

Neither of the examples use a "class member variable".

The first

```
AB = 123
```

is a constant.

The second

```
ab = 245
```

is a local variable. It is not in scope inside the method definition, which is why you get the error.

---

This is how to declare and use a class variable (from within an instance method):

```
class C
  @@ab = 678
  def print_var
    print @@ab
  end
end
C.new.print_var
```

Ruby uses the prefix `@@` to identify class variables, and the most common convention is to use lower-case letters (possibly with numbers and underscores).

---

This is how to declare and use a class *instance* variable (again, from within an instance method - note that we need a class/singleton method available in order to access it in the first place):

```
class D
  @ab = 890
  def self.get_ab
    @ab
  end

  def print_var
    print self.class.get_ab
  end
end
D.new.print_var
```

Ruby uses the prefix `@` to identify instance variables. When you assign or use them in a class/singleton context they will be instance variables of the class.

Using class instance variables is slightly more complex, but is used quite often, because it  gives more options when working with inheritance.